# JS regex replace number

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to get my head around some regex using JS .replace to replace an integer with a string.

For example, the string could be:

```
var string = 'image[testing][hello][0][welcome]';
```

I want to replace the '0' with another value. I was originally using this:

```
string.replace( /\[\d\]/g, '[newvalue]');
```

But when we start replacing double digits or more (12, 200, 3204, you get what I mean), it stops working properly. Not sure how to get it functioning the way I want it too.

Thanks in advance. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to specify multiple digits:

```
string.replace( /\[\d+\]/g, '[newvalue]');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6AMwJ/)

(Note the demo uses jQuery to iterate through the nodes, but it's merely a convenience, and has no bearing on the regular expression, it just demonstrates its function.)

The reason your original didn't work, I think, was because `\d` matches only a single digit, whereas the `+` operator/character specifies the preceding (in this case digit) character one or more times.

Reference:

- [JavaScript Regular Expressions, at the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

`string.replace( /\[\d+\]/g, '[newvalue]');`

That should match all digits in brackets.